# How to open Drawer from another component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am having a material UI `Drawer` on my index page, which should be opened by getting triggered `onClick`. I want to open it from my Header component - is it possible?

I tried to pass the props, but it does not work.

This is my index.jsx

```
    const [cartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false);


<Header
                countCartItems={cartItems.length}
                cartItems={cartItems}
                onAdd={onAdd}
                onRemove={onRemove}
                setCartOpen={setCartOpen}
            />
            <Drawer
                anchor="top"
                open={cartOpen}
                onClose={() => setCartOpen(false)}
            >
                Hey, it's opened
            </Drawer>
```

And my Header component, where I am trying to `setOpen(true)`

```
const Header = (props, setCartOpen) = {
.......
 <button onClick={() => setCartOpen(true)}>
<Badge badgeContent={props.countCartItems}/>
 </button>
......
```

This is usually how I am passing values/props/states from one component to another, but in this case where state is boolean it doesn't want to trigger it. Is there a way how to handle it as simple as possible?

Answer (score 0):

In functional components props are passed as the only argument and its an **object**.

You need to change your code as

Option - 1: Since they are objects you can do **Object Destructuring**

```
const Header = ({setCartOpen, countCartItems, ... }) = {
.......
 <button onClick={() => setCartOpen(true)}>
<Badge badgeContent={countCartItems}/>
 </button>
......
```

Option - 2: You can access them via the `.` notation as you access any other property in an object

```
const Header = (props) = {
.......
 <button onClick={() => props.setCartOpen(true)}>
<Badge badgeContent={props.countCartItems}/>
 </button>
......
```